# Gulp-watch issue

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I am having a small problem with gulp-watch. When i change something in the styles folder(a .css file) the watch won't trigger. I just wan't to write a copy to another folder. The html task works fine, but the css won't trigger. Also all the programming i am doing in ubuntu if that makes any difference.

```
    var gulp = require('gulp');

    gulp.task('html', function(){
        console.log("Changes have been made to the html file!");
    });

    gulp.task('styles', function(){
         return gulp.src('./app/assets/styles/styles.css').pipe(gulp.dest('./app/assets/temp/styles'));
    });


    gulp.task('watch', function() {

        gulp.watch('./app/index.html', function(){
            gulp.start('html');
        });

        gulp.watch('app/assets/styles/**/*.css'), function(){
            gulp.start('styles');
        };
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I had an extra ) at:

```
'app/assets/styles/**/*.css') <<<<
```